# Android Market Filters and Build Target

Tags: android, google-play

I want to set in project properties build target 2.2 (api level 8)

In the manifest.xml `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>` is declared.

Did anybody tried, if any user (with min. Android 1.5) see application in the market?

Could some other problems occur because of different SDK for building and in manifest?!

Thank you,

Mur

P.s.
You would probably ask, why do I want to do that thing.
Just wanted that users of Android 2.2. could move app to SD card and and have read this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/move-to-sd-card/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you set your `minSdkVersion` to Android 1.5, you should be fine.  Just make sure you don't make any newer API calls for people running older versions of Android.  You can check a user's build version with [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).  If you're only adding the Froyo move to SD card feature, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I've tested this app in several emulator versions. The biggest worries are, if all users of 1.5+ can see it in Android Market. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Mur it should show up for 1.5 users with the minsdkvalue.  I have an app with target of 1.6 with minsdk of 1.5 and I've had no problems with 1.5 users not being able to access my app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what I usually do, build an app based on 1.5 APIs but add Apps2SD in the Manifest and build using 2.2 but with minSdkVersion=3. It works fine all users of 1.5+ can use the app and 2.2 users can move it to SD.

Comment: I repeat my comment to Bryan. I've tested this app in several emulator versions. The biggest worries are, if all users of 1.5+ can see it in Android Market. Thank you for your answer